# Cannot begin transaction on MS SQL Express server with ADO

Tags: sql-server, ado

I want to update some rows in the MS SQL database from a C++. Problem is, I cannot create transaction. Every time I try to execute `Ado::Connection::BeginTrans` I get an error:

> A request to establish a connection with the transaction manager was
>   denied.

I've installed a new copy of SQL Server 2017 Express Edition on my local computer (Win 10 Pro) and created a new DB called `test`.

Connection string:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=SNAIL\SQLEXPRESS;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

What should I do to get rid of this error?

EDIT:

Part of the source code:

```
#import <msado15.dll> rename_namespace("ADO2"), raw_interfaces_only, raw_native_types, named_guids, no_smart_pointers

const auto connection_string = L"Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=SNAIL\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=SSPI";

// create connection
Ref<ADO2::_Connection> m_DbConnection;
m_DbConnection->put_Mode(ADO2::adModeReadWrite);
m_DbConnection->put_ConnectionTimeout(5);
m_DbConnection->Open(connection_string, nullptr, nullptr, ADO2::adConnectUnspecified)


class InAdoTransaction {
private:
    Ref<ADO2::_Connection>  m_DbConnection;
    bool m_Commited;

public:
    InAdoTransaction(ADO2::_Connection *Connection) {
        m_DbConnection = Connection;
        m_Commited = false;

        long transaction_level;
        HRESULT er = m_DbConnection->BeginTrans(&transaction_level);
        ASSERT(er == S_OK);
    }

    ~InAdoTransaction() {
        if (!m_Commited) {
            Rollback();
        }
    }

    void Rollback() {
        m_DbConnection->RollbackTrans();
    }

    void Commit() {
        m_DbConnection->CommitTrans();
        m_Commited = true;
    }
};


// usage
HRESULT FUNC StoreMetadata()
{
    HRESULT er = S_OK;

    Ref<ADO2::_Recordset> rst;

    InAdoTransaction transaction(m_DbConnection);

    if (FAILED(m_DbConnection->Execute(QUERY_TRUNCATE_METADATA_TABLE, nullptr, 0, OUT(rst)))) {
        return E_CANNOT_STORE_METADATA;
    }

    ...

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Post your code. Transactions work with ADO. It's a 25+ year old technology after all

Comment: Some code might help. The docs offer an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/begintrans-committrans-and-rollbacktrans-methods-example-vc) that is truly horrendous, but might give you a clue as to what you're doing wrong. (Definitely do not use the `sqloledb` provider it shows you there, though; `sqlncli11` is fine, or else the newer `msoledbsql`, which needs a separate install.)

Comment: Have you restarted since installing SQL Server Express? Is the Distributed Transaction Coordinator service running?

Comment: You probably *shouldn't* use `SQLNCLI11` either. [It's deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-2017) and all new development went to the ODBC and OLEDB drivers. ADO works on top of OLEDB anyway, so using the OLEDB client with `"Provider='sqloledb'` won't change the code at all

Comment: That particular error means that somehow, the code tried to start a *distributed* transaction. That requires DTC and is probably *not* what you want. A simple `BEGIN TRAN` command doesn't need DTC. `Connection.BeginTrans()` shouldn't need DTC either.

Comment: On the other hand, using eg a linked server in a query requires a distributed transaction and will try to use MS DTC.

Comment: I've tried 'sqloledb' as well, but the behaviour is the same. + I added a code snippet to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. The whole problem was in a recordset I've created on tables `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`. Locktype of this recordset was set to `LockType::adLockReadOnly` and that caused the problem. I've changed it to `LockType::adLockOptimistic` an now everything works like a charm.

But, it's a shame that the provider returns such a misleading error message.